# TypeError: connectionString.startsWith is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I try to connect to the MongoDB this error happens. I have installed MongoDB in my package.json and all the other models but when I run the code it's connect to the port perfectly but as soon as I try to insert a collection the error happens “undertOne() is not defined”.
Moviedb.js

```
import app from './server.js';
import ReviewsDAO from "./dao/reviewsDAO.js";
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const MongoClient=mongodb.MongoClient

//Load the environment variables from the .env file
dotenv.config();
//Access the environment variables

const mongo_username = process.env.MONGO_USERNAME;
const mongo_password = process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD;
//access to the db 
const uri = new MongoClient(`mongodb+srv://${mongo_username}:${mongo_password}@cluster0.b5f7prn.mongodb.net/test`);

const port=4444;

MongoClient.connect(
  uri,
  {
    maxPoolSize: 50,
    wtimeoutMS: 2500,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })

  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    console.error("Error connecting to the database:", err.message)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  

  .then(async client => {
    await ReviewsDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
```

Server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import reviews from './api/reviews.route.js';

//creating web server
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviews);
app.use('*', (req,res)=>res.status(404).json({error:"Not found"}));

//to listen to the router 
app.listen( 4444, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port 4444`);
  });

export default app;
```

I have tried debugging the code the error appears in moviedb.js in this section:

```
MongoClient.connect(
  uri,
  {
    maxPoolSize: 50,
    wtimeoutMS: 2500,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })

  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    console.error("Error connecting to the database:", err.message)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  

  .then(async client => {
    await ReviewsDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
```

reviews.route.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import ReviewsCtrl from "./reviews.controller.js";

const router=express.Router();

router.route("/movie/:id").get(ReviewsCtrl.apiGetReviews);
router.route("/new").post(ReviewsCtrl.apiPostReview);
router.route("/:id")
    .get(ReviewsCtrl.apiGetReviews)
    .put(ReviewsCtrl.apiUpdateReview)
    .delete(ReviewsCtrl.apiDeleteReview)

export default router;
```

Comment: can you plz show us `api/reviews.route.js`'s content ? and copy / paste the complete error ?

Comment: You use both `new MongoClient` and `MongoClient.connect`, which is redundant. Use `uri.connect` instead, as in [this example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/#connection-uri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `MongoClient` instance as a uri to MongoClient.connect, which is wrong. Use this instead

```
MongoClient.connect(`mongodb+srv://${mongo_username}:${mongo_password}@cluster0.b5f7prn.mongodb.net/test`,
{
  maxPoolSize: 50,
  wtimeoutMS: 2500,
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked. But when I try to add to the collection this error appears :curl -X POST http://localhost:4444/api/v1/reviews/new -H “Content-Type:application/json” -d ‘{“movieId”:12,”user”:”sara”,”review”:”good”}’. The error :curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL